# Rails / omitted from link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, url, hyperlink

I am using a Gem to communicate with FreeagentCentral via their API. I have the following code to display a link to the relevant freeagent project:

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag('/images/icons/Spinning Beach Ball.png')} Freeagent Project", "#{Freeagent::Base.site.to_s + Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id).gsub(/\A\//, '').gsub!(/.xml/,'')}" if @kase.freeagent_id %>
```

The problem - There is a / omitted from the URL which makes the url like this:

```
https://XXXXX.freeagentcentral.comprojects/12345
```

where it should be:

```
https://XXXXX.freeagentcentral.com/projects/12345
```

This may be simple, but to me - it's driving me crazy!

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: What does `Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id)` return? It's difficult to tell what's going on in the regexp without seeing the original input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Freeagent::Base.site` is retuning `'https://XXXXX.freeagentcentral.com'`. In which case, you just need to add the `/` into your string between the site and project parts. Try the following:

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag('/images/icons/Spinning Beach Ball.png')} Freeagent Project", 
  "#{Freeagent::Base.site}/#{Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id).gsub(/\A\//, '').gsub!(/.xml/,'')}" if @kase.freeagent_id %>
```

---

*Edit:*

Looking at this more closely, `gsub(/\A\//, '')` is removing a `/` from the start of the string returned by `Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id)`. Assuming that `element_path` does actually return a string with a leading `/`, the better answer would  be to remove the first `gsub` call:

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag('/images/icons/Spinning Beach Ball.png')} Freeagent Project", 
  "#{Freeagent::Base.site}#{Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id).gsub!(/.xml/,'')}" if @kase.freeagent_id %>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! For some reason I thought the / should go further into the string. Thanks again!